# Remedial measures for soon-to-expire keystore

Tags: android

I have an apk signed with a keystore that will expire in 2 years. Currently the apk is signed with just v1 scheme. I know there are v2, v3 and v4 signing schemes today. Is it possible to use these new signing schemes to append a new signature to the apk so that users don't need a reinstallation before the expiry date?

I have tried `--append-signature` option, but it cannot replace the installed one.

```
apksigner.jar sign --ks NEW-KEY-STORE --v1-signing-enabled=false \
    --v3-signing-enabled=false --append-signature V1-SIGNED-APK
```